# Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am trying to make a Cloud Formation to build quite an extensive AWS solution. I am having trouble creating the S3 bucket and keep getting the following error.

I get the below error:

```
Unable to validate the following destination configurations (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: ***********; S3 Extended Request ID: ********** Proxy: null)
```

And this is what the S3 Bucket and respective IAM Permissions look like.

```
S3Bucket:
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-cl24503833"
      BucketEncryption: 
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration: 
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault: 
              SSEAlgorithm: "AES256"
            BucketKeyEnabled: true
      LifecycleConfiguration: 
        Rules: 
          - Id: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-LifecycleRule"
            ExpirationInDays: 7
            Status: "Enabled"
      CorsConfiguration: 
        CorsRules: 
          - AllowedHeaders: 
              - "x-amz-*"
              - "Authorization"
              - "Content-Type"
            AllowedMethods: 
              - "PUT"
              - "HEAD"
            AllowedOrigins: 
              - !Sub "https://${AWS::Region}.console.aws.amazon.com"
      NotificationConfiguration: 
        LambdaConfigurations: 
          - Event: "s3:ObjectCreated:Put"
            Filter: 
              S3Key: 
                Rules: 
                  - Name: "Prefix"
                    Value: "processor/results/"
            Function: !GetAtt LambdaFunction2.Arn
          - Event: "s3:ObjectCreated:Put"
            Filter: 
              S3Key: 
                Rules: 
                  - Name: "Prefix"
                    Value: "logical_disk/results/"
            Function: !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn
          - Event: "s3:ObjectCreated:Put"
            Filter: 
              S3Key: 
                Rules: 
                  - Name: "Prefix"
                    Value: "paging_file/results/"
            Function: !GetAtt LambdaFunction3.Arn
      VersioningConfiguration: 
        Status: "Enabled"
      OwnershipControls: 
        Rules: 
          - ObjectOwnership: "BucketOwnerEnforced"
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration: 
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
```

I was skeptical that it was to do with IAM permissions so I added the second IAM role to the existing role.

```
LambdaS3AccessRole:
      Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
      Properties:
          Path: "/"
          RoleName: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-BucketRole'
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Principal:
                  Service: "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
          MaxSessionDuration: 3600
          ManagedPolicyArns:
            - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSNSFullAccess"
            - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
            - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"
            - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonTimestreamFullAccess"
          Description: "Allows Lambda functions to call AWS services on your behalf."
```

The role I added after:

```
LambdaS3ExplicitAccessPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      Roles: 
        - !Ref LambdaS3AccessRole
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - s3:GetObject
              - s3:GetObjectVersion
              - s3:ListBucket
            Resource:
              - !GetAtt S3Bucket.Arn
      PolicyName: LambdaS3ExplicitAccess
```